# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' 5

Tags: objective-c

i am getting this error while running my app:
my code is:

```
- (IBAction)yes:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *msgbox=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warrning" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    if ([_usernametextbox.text length]>0)
    {
        if ([_passwordtextfield.text length]>0)
        {
            NSMutableString *ms=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:url,_usernametextbox.text,_passwordtextfield];
            NSURL *serviceurl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:ms];
            NSError *error=nil;
            NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:serviceurl options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
            NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            NSString *jsondata=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            SBJSON *parsedata=[[SBJSON alloc] init];
            dic=[parsedata objectWithString:jsondata error:nil];
            if([dic count]>0)
            {
                NSMutableString *st=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:[dic objectForKey:@"loginResult:@""+"]]; //@" " withString:@"+"
                if ([st isEqualToString:@"YES"])
                {
                    UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"accept" message:@"correct username" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alert show];


                }
                else
                {
                    UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Invalid UserName and Password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alert show];

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            msgbox.message=@"Please Enter Password...";
            [msgbox show];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        msgbox.message=@"Please Enter Username...";
        [msgbox show];


}
```

I get the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData
>   initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]: nil URL argument'

on the line:

```
NSMutableString *st=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:[dic objectForKey:@"loginResult:@""+"]]; //@" " withString:@"+" if ([st isEqualToString:@"YES"])
```

Comment: i had given url... here i removed

Comment: i am getting this error on this line ..
NSMutableString *st=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:[dic objectForKey:@"loginResult:@""+"]]; //@" " withString:@"+"
                if ([st isEqualToString:@"YES"]) 
i had checked after applyaing breakpoints?

Comment: I edited the question based on your comment, anyway have you tried with NSMutableString *st=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:[dic objectForKey:@"loginResult"]]; ?

Comment: yes i had tried... but same error

Comment: i waz trying for 3 hours but ... my problem is not solved

Comment: put this after the creation of dic and check what is the output on your console:  NSLog([dic allKeys]); or you could put a breakpoint and inspect the dic variable, what is the output?

Comment: This is not "debug my code" site. The exception clearly states what the problem is.

Comment: ok wait i will tell after putting breakpoints 2 mins

Comment: will you plz give me a link that how to parse json data???

Comment: self first_ViewController * 0x07191b60
data NSConcreteData * 0x071d5f60
dic __NSDictionaryM * 0x071d3730
error NSError * 0x00000000
jsondata __NSCFString * 0x071d35c0

Comment: when i inspect  dic variable it is giving key/valuepairs